# bash script (or something else) to automate docker tag docker push

Tags: bash, docker

Looking for help to write a bash script to automate my docker workflow, or open to suggestions what to do instead

Current workflow is:
1.

```
me$ docker images
REPOSITORY                                                TAG                         IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
abc.amazonaws.com/XYZ/XYZ-server                          0.0.3-7-g45b4b4232e         cf324458299c        8 minutes ago       936MB
```

2.

```
me$ docker tag cf324458299c abc.amazonaws.com/XYZ/XYZ-server:0.0.3-7-g45b4b4232e
me$ docker tag <last_image_id> <last_repo_id>:<last_tag>
```

3.

```
me$ docker push abc.amazonaws.com/XYZ/XYZ-server:0.0.3-7-g45b4b4232e
```

how could I automate this in a bash script so I can put it as an alias?

thank you very much

Comment: Contains output of `docker images` always only two rows?

Comment: @Cyrus No, in the general case there is no such guarantee. There will be as many output lines as there are images, plus the header line; but a better solution is probably to use Docker's options to restrict to images matching a specific pattern, and request machine-readable output.

Comment: Better still is to pass a `-t` option when you build the image in the first place.

Answer (score 2):

You would just extract the needed data and use them.

```
# 1. 
if ! tmp=$(docker images --format '{{.Repository}}\t{{.Tag}}\t{{.ID}}' | grep 'abc.amazonaws.com/XYZ/XYZ-server'); then
   : #hadnle error
fi
IFS=$'\t' read -r last_image_id last_repo_id last_tag <<<"$tmp"
# 2.
docker tag "$last_image_id" "$last_repo_id:$last_tag"
# 3.
docker push "$last_repo_id:$last_tag"
```

Answer (score -1):

Steps:

1. create a bash script sample.sh and add these lines in it

```
var="amazonaws"

echo docker tag $(docker images | grep $var | awk '{print $3}') $(docker images | grep $var | awk '{print $1}'):$(docker images | grep $var | awk '{print $2}')
docker tag $(docker images | grep $var | awk '{print $3}') $(docker images | grep $var | awk '{print $1}'):$(docker images | grep $var | awk '{print $2}')

echo docker push $(docker images | grep $var | awk '{print $1}'):$(docker images | grep $var | awk '{print $2}')
docker push $(docker images | grep $var | awk '{print $1}'):$(docker images | grep $var | awk '{print $2}')
```

2. `chmod +x sample.sh`
3. execute as: `sample.sh`

Comment: Whatever you are hoping to accomplish, **`chmod 777` is *wrong* and *dangerous.*** You will want to revert to sane permissions ASAP (for your use case, probably `chmod 755`) and if you have had world writable system files on a public-facing system, at the very least investigate whether it could have been breached and used as a pivot point for breaking into your organization’s network.

Comment: Also, this reads like a best-of compilation of shell programming antipatterns. Run this against http://shellcheck.net/ and fix the problems it reports for a start. Perhaps see also several of the topics on the [UUCA page](http://www.iki.fi/era/unix/award.html)